# Java String.format - method format(String, Object []) not applicable for argument format(String, float)

Tags: java

I use this code in my project which is independent from other project.

```
float trg1 = 2.3f;
String.format("%.2f",tgr1).replace(",", ".");
```

When I insert this in other project which is depends from other project I get error like this:

> method format(String, Object []) not applicable for argument format(String, float)

Comment: I didn't realise that '.' can turn into a ',' in a format string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you somehow tried to use a pre-1.5 compiler, while still targeting JRE 1.5 or higher? That's all I can think of... this should work absolutely fine (once you've got the variable names right, of course).

Are you able to use other Java 5 features (e.g. generics) in the failing project?

Comment: I was forget to set JRE on other project to higher version.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're on a different compiler version. That code compiles properly with the 1.6 compiler. It doesn't **do** anything, but it definitely compiles and runs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like autoboxing isn't kicking in where you might expect it to.  I would be almost certain you can force it to work if you change the first line to:

```
Float trg1 = 2.3f; // Notice uppercase Float
```

What version of Java are you using, by the way?  Java 5 should autobox the `float` into a `Float` in order to pass it to the varargs method call.  If my suggested fix doesn't compile either, then you're definitely dealing with a pre-1.5 compiler that doesn't understand autoboxing.